# Assign specific colours to data in Matplotlib pie chart

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, charts, pie-chart

I'm trying to create pie charts with `matplotlib` in which the colour of each category is fixed.

I've got a function which creates a pie chart from sets of value and category data. Here's one example:

```
Category     Value
TI           65
Con          43
FR           40
TraI         40
Bug          38
Data         22
Int          15
KB           12
Other        8
Dep          7
PW           6
Uns          5
Perf         4
Dep          3
```

The problem is that the data differs from one instance to another, and that in turn changes the order of the categories. Thus, each category gets labelled a different colour each time I generate a chart. I could sort the data alphabetically every time, but that causes two problems: some categories are missing from some datasets, and I'd prefer it sorted by size anyway so that the smallest wedges are oriented horizontally.

How can I set `matplotlib` to assign colours depending on, say, the index of a `pandas.Series`?

Here's the code that I'm using to generate a pie chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

slices = [62, 39, 39, 38, 37, 21, 15,  9,  6,  7,  6,  5,  4, 3]

cmap = plt.cm.prism
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0., 1., len(slices)))

labels = [u'TI', u'Con', u'FR', u'TraI', u'Bug', u'Data', u'Int', u'KB', u'Other', u'Dep', u'PW', u'Uns', u'Perf', u'Dep']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 10])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

pie_wedge_collection = ax.pie(slices, colors=colors, labels=labels, labeldistance=1.05, autopct=make_autopct(slices))

for pie_wedge in pie_wedge_collection[0]:
    pie_wedge.set_edgecolor('white')

titlestring = 'Issues'

ax.set_title(titlestring)
```

EDIT: I forgot to explain the `autopct` function, it's for adding value and percentage labels:

```
def make_autopct(values):
    def my_autopct(pct):
        total = sum(values)
        val = int(round(pct*total/100.0))
        return '{p:.2f}%  ({v:d})'.format(p=pct,v=val)
    return my_autopct
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an idea you could try. Make a dictionary from your labels and colors, so each color is mapped to a label. Then, after making the pie chart, go in an assign the `facecolor` of the wedge using this dictionary.

Here's an *untested* bit of code which might do what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mypie(slices,labels,colors):

    colordict={}
    for l,c in zip(labels,colors):
        print l,c
        colordict[l]=c

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 10])
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    pie_wedge_collection = ax.pie(slices, labels=labels, labeldistance=1.05)#, autopct=make_autopct(slices))

    for pie_wedge in pie_wedge_collection[0]:
        pie_wedge.set_edgecolor('white')
        pie_wedge.set_facecolor(colordict[pie_wedge.get_label()])

    titlestring = 'Issues'

    ax.set_title(titlestring)

    return fig,ax,pie_wedge_collection

slices = [37, 39, 39, 38, 62, 21, 15,  9,  6,  7,  6,  5,  4, 3]
cmap = plt.cm.prism
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0., 1., len(slices)))
labels = [u'TI', u'Con', u'FR', u'TraI', u'Bug', u'Data', u'Int', u'KB', u'Other', u'Dep', u'PW', u'Uns', u'Perf', u'Dep']

fig,ax,pie_wedge_collection = mypie(slices,labels,colors)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go.

Comment: isn't there an easier approach ??

Comment: it works!  Also, if you want to repeat the default color palette, do this for the 1st pie chart: 
```colordict[pie_wedge.get_label()] = pie_wedge.get_facecolor() ```

Comment: @RomainJouin For an easier solution you can construct a dictionary which maps each label to a colour. You can then pass a list comprehension to the `colors` argument of `plt.pie`.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a simpler solution to @tmdavison's answer.

Let's first see the problem with an MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs']
sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax[0].pie(sizes, labels=labels)
ax[1].pie(sizes[1:], labels=labels[1:])
```

This produces the problem plots:

[image]

The problem is that in the left-hand plot, `Hogs` is coloured in orange, but in the right-hand plot `Hogs` is coloured in blue (with a similar mix-up for `Logs` and `Dogs`).

We would like the colours for the labels to be the same across both plots. We can do this by specifying a dictionary of colours to use:

```py
labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs']
sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]
colours = {'Frogs': 'C0',
           'Hogs': 'C1',
           'Dogs': 'C2',
           'Logs': 'C3'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax[0].pie(sizes,
          labels=labels,
          colors=[colours[key] for key in labels])

ax[1].pie(sizes[1:],
          labels=labels[1:],
          colors=[colours[key] for key in labels[1:]])
```

This works to create the plot:

[image]

Here we see that the labels are represented by the same colours across both plots, as desired.

If you have lots of categories it can be cumbersome to manually set a colour for each category. In this case you could construct the `colours` dictionary as:

```
colours = dict(zip(labels, plt.cm.tab10.colors[:len(labels)]))
```

If you have more than 10 categories you would instead use:

```
colours = dict(zip(labels, plt.cm.tab20.colors[:len(labels)]))
```