# What does indexing the matplotlib axis do in a loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib, indexing, pie-chart, axes

I saw a post on assigning the same colors across multiple pie plots in Matplotlib [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206282/assign-specific-colours-to-data-in-matplotlib-pie-chart)

But there's something I don't understand about indexing the axis object.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mypie(slices,labels,colors):

    colordict={}
    for l,c in zip(labels,colors):
        print l,c
        colordict[l]=c

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 10])
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    pie_wedge_collection = ax.pie(slices, labels=labels, labeldistance=1.05)#, autopct=make_autopct(slices))

    for pie_wedge in pie_wedge_collection[0]:
        pie_wedge.set_edgecolor('white')
        pie_wedge.set_facecolor(colordict[pie_wedge.get_label()])

    titlestring = 'Issues'

    ax.set_title(titlestring)

    return fig,ax,pie_wedge_collection

slices = [37, 39, 39, 38, 62, 21, 15,  9,  6,  7,  6,  5,  4, 3]
cmap = plt.cm.prism
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0., 1., len(slices)))
labels = [u'TI', u'Con', u'FR', u'TraI', u'Bug', u'Data', u'Int', u'KB', u'Other', u'Dep', u'PW', u'Uns', u'Perf', u'Dep']

    fig,ax,pie_wedge_collection = mypie(slices,labels,colors)

plt.show()
```

In the line: `for pie_wedge in pie_wedge_collection[0]` what does the index [0] do? The code doesn't work if I don't use it or use `pie_wedge_collection[1]`

Doesn't the ax object here only have one plot here?  So I don't understand what the index is doing.

Comment: [API-docs](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie): just look at the returned values.

Comment: Or print out `pie_wedge_collection` and `type(pie_wedge_collection)`. Then you see, why element 0 is different from element 1 in this tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Matplotlib documentation, `pie()` returns two or three lists:

1. A list of `matplotlib.patches.Wedge`
2. A list of `matplotlib.text.Text` labels
3. (conditionally) A list of `matplotlib.text.Text` data labels

Your code needs to manipulate the edge and face colors of the `Wedge` objects returned by `pie()`, which are in the first list (zero index) in the return value, `pie_wedge_collection`.