# Python matplotlib how to map colours to 'x-values' in pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'product': [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2], 'market': [1,2,1,2,5,6,7,1,6,7], 'value': [500,300,100,200,400,100,200,100,300,900]})
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3)
for m in range(3):
    df.loc[df['product']==m].plot(ax=axes[m], kind='pie', y='value', figsize=(15,5))
```

[image: Plot]

How can I pass a colourmap into the plotfunction such that the colour for each market would be the same in all 3 piecharts?
If that is not possible, does anyone have any other suggestions how to achieve this, maybe by adding dummy rows in a halfway elegant fashion?

Note. I am using py3.6 and the latest release on pandas

Comment: There was a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35206282/11021886)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a lookup dictionary for the different categories and use it to create a list of colors for each pie chart.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame({'product': [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2], 
                 'market': [1,2,1,2,5,6,7,1,6,7], 
                 'value': [500,300,100,200,400,100,200,100,300,900]})

cdict = dict(zip(np.unique(df["market"].values), plt.cm.tab10.colors))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3)
for m in range(3):
    data = df.loc[df['product']==m]
    data.plot(ax=axes[m], kind='pie', y='value', figsize=(15,5), 
              colors=[cdict[v] for v in data["market"]])

plt.show()
```

[image]